# Checkable listview in android with delete action menu

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview, when i do long press  a checkbox should appear on each listitem and i want to check that items, after checking i'm selecting delete action menu, so that the checked item should get deleted in listview and list should be refreshed. I need help in creating checkable listview and action menu. Please Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here from below link you can find listview with checkbox

http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-multiple-select-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make the checkbox visible when long press the item of listview

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {


  Checkbox.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);


    });
```